# Using RunOnUI to pass data from a Service to an Activity

Tags: android, service, google-glass

Need a bit of help here, I am trying to create a service that uses the microphone to listen to peaks in audio frequency. This service should run in the background and update the UI with frequency information when there is a peak. Currently the app launches and then FC's due to what seems like its running out of memory. I've tried debugging and following the threads but I am new at this and can't seem to decipher what I am doing wrong.

Here is my Activity:

```
public class RTAactivity extends Activity  {

    private static final String TAG = "RtaTest";
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rta_view);

        intent = new Intent(this, AnalyzeService.class);

    }
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();  // check logcat 
            updateUI(intent);       
        }
    };    

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();       
        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(AnalyzeService.ANALYZE_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        stopService(intent);        
    }   
    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
        String freq = intent.getStringExtra("freq"); 
        String dB = intent.getStringExtra("dB");
        Log.d(TAG, freq);
        Log.d(TAG, dB);

        TextView TVfreq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_freq);    
        TextView decibels = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_decibels);
        TVfreq.setText(freq);
        decibels.setText(dB);
    }
}
```

and here is the service:

```
public class AnalyzeService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "AnalyzerService";
public static final String ANALYZE_ACTION =     "com.kjacksonmusic.glassrta.displayevent";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intent;



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    intent = new Intent(ANALYZE_ACTION);    
}

 @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(RunOnUI);    //sendUpdatestoUI
        handler.postDelayed(RunOnUI, 500); // 0.5 second

    }
 private Runnable RunOnUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();  // check logcat 
            DisplayAudioInfo();     
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1 seconds
        }
    };    

    private void DisplayAudioInfo() {
       Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayAudioInfo");
       int frequency;
       AudioRecord recorder;
       boolean recording;                       
       int numCrossing,p;
       short audioData[];   

int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)*3; //get the buffer size to use with this audio record

recorder = new AudioRecord (AudioSource.MIC,8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize); //instantiate the AudioRecorder 

recording=true; //variable to use start or stop recording
audioData = new short [bufferSize]; //short array that pcm data is put into.


while (recording) {  //loop while recording is needed
    if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) // check to see if the recorder has initialized yet.
    if (recorder.getRecordingState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)
          recorder.startRecording();  //check to see if the Recorder has stopped or is not recording, and make it record.

    else {

    recorder.read(audioData,0,bufferSize); //read the PCM audio data into the audioData array

    //Now we need to decode the PCM data using the Zero Crossings Method

      numCrossing=0; //initialize your number of zero crossings to 0

      for (p=0;p<1000;p+=4) {
             if (audioData[p]>0 && audioData[p+1]<=0) numCrossing++;
              if (audioData[p]<0 && audioData[p+1]>=0) numCrossing++;
              if (audioData[p+1]>0 && audioData[p+2]<=0) numCrossing++;
              if (audioData[p+1]<0 && audioData[p+2]>=0) numCrossing++;
              if (audioData[p+2]>0 && audioData[p+3]<=0) numCrossing++;
              if (audioData[p+2]<0 && audioData[p+3]>=0) numCrossing++;
              if (audioData[p+3]>0 && audioData[p+4]<=0) numCrossing++;
              if (audioData[p+3]<0 && audioData[p+4]>=0) numCrossing++;
              }//for p

        for (p=(bufferSize/4)*4;p<bufferSize-1;p++) {
              if (audioData[p]>0 && audioData[p+1]<=0) numCrossing++;
              if (audioData[p]<0 && audioData[p+1]>=0) numCrossing++;
              }


        frequency=numCrossing*4;
        intent.putExtra("freq", frequency);
        intent.putExtra("dB", 100);  ///place holder for now. 
        sendBroadcast(intent);  


                 }//else recorder started

    } //while recording

    if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) recorder.stop(); //stop the recorder before ending the thread
    recorder.release(); //release the recorders resources
    recorder=null; //set the recorder to be garbage collected.
        } // run


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        handler.removeCallbacks(RunOnUI);       //sendUpdatesToUI
        super.onDestroy();
    }    

}
```

LOGCAT OUTPUT:

```
06-25 21:54:20.380: I/ActivityManager(3122): START u0 {cmp=com.kjacksonmusic.glassrta/.RTAactivity} from pid 21580

06-25 21:54:20.458: W/Resources(3122): Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x208 "res/anim/accelerate_interpolator.xml" a=1 r=0x10a0005}

06-25 21:54:20.607: I/SystemUpdateService(3573): cancelUpdate (empty URL)

06-25 21:54:20.716: I/SystemUpdateService(3573): cancelUpdate (empty URL)

06-25 21:54:20.833: I/ActivityManager(3122): Displayed 
com.kjacksonmusic.glassrta/.RTAactivity: +359ms

06-25 21:54:21.107: D/AnalyzerService(21580): entered DisplayAudioInfo

06-25 21:54:35.161: I/PowerManagerService(3122): Going to sleep due to screen timeout...

06-25 21:54:35.442: D/SurfaceFlinger(120): Screen released, type=0 flinger=0xb882c450

06-25 21:54:35.521: I/WindowManager(3122): Screen turned off...

06-25 21:54:35.614: I/HeadGestureManager(3122): Unregistering listener: 
com.google.android.glass.server.SystemServerHub$4@20ecfce0 for head gesture: NUDGE

06-25 21:54:35.614: D/HeadGestureContainer(3122): Stopping detector: com.google.android.glass.head.HeadNudgeUpDetector@20ec8be8 name=NUDGE

06-25 21:54:35.622: D/RunnableDetector(3122): run() is exiting!

06-25 21:54:35.622: I/MPL-storeload(3122): mpl state size = 5584

06-25 21:54:35.630: E/MPL-storeload(3122): calData from inv_save_mpl_states, size=2

06-25 21:54:35.630: I/MPL-storeload(3122): cal data size to write = 5584

06-25 21:54:35.630: I/MPL-storeload(3122): Bytes written = 5584

06-25 21:54:35.638: I/HeadGestureManager(3122): Registering listener: com.google.android.glass.server.SystemServerHub$4@20ecfce0 for head gesture: GLOBAL_LOOK_UP

06-25 21:54:35.638: V/GlassInputHub(3122): Cancelling all event sequences.

06-25 21:54:35.638: V/GlassInputHub(3122): Cancelling event sequence: Camera key.

06-25 21:54:35.638: V/GlassInputHub(3122): Cancelling event sequence: Power key.

06-25 21:54:35.638: V/GlassInputHub(3122): Cancelling event sequence: Viewfinder switch.

06-25 21:54:35.638: V/GlassInputHub(3122): Cancelling event sequence: Touchpad.

06-25 21:54:35.708: I/VoiceEngine[20e0026c](3363): Screen is off and current config does not allow screen off.

06-25 21:54:35.724: W/VoiceEngine[20e0026c](3363): Transition to VoiceConfig [] requested, but already in that config.

06-25 21:54:35.817: I/GlassUserEventService[20dd9364](3708): Performance stats: [object: com.google.common.logging.GlassExtensionsNano$GlassUserEventPerformanceStats {   
batteryChargeWhenFullUah_: 403000    totalKernelMs_: 62401830    totalBytesSent_: 123808401    bitField0_: 8191    boardTemperatureMilliCentigrade_: 43810    frequencyScalingGovernor_: 0    availableMemoryKb_: 49148    isLowMemory_: false    qpassedFractional_: 13445    qpassedInteger_: 16636    reportedSoc_: 95    batteryTemperatureMilliCentigrade_: 28100    batteryStateOfChargeUah_: 380000    totalMemoryKb_: 596116    unknownFieldData: null    cachedSize: -1}]

06-25 21:54:36.028: W/ActivityManager(3122): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{20ede224 u0 com.kjacksonmusic.glassrta/.RTAactivity t1}

06-25 21:54:39.560: I/GCM(3573): GCM message com.google.glass.home 0:1403747679192023%0#71a16bb9f9fd7ecd

06-25 21:54:39.622: D/ConnectivityService(3122): reportNetworkCondition(1, 100)

06-25 21:54:39.630: D/ConnectivityService(3122): handleInetConditionChange: net=1, condition=100,mActiveDefaultNetwork=1

06-25 21:54:39.630: D/ConnectivityService(3122): handleInetConditionChange: starting a change hold

06-25 21:54:39.669: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(3321): onReceive: 
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE

06-25 21:54:39.669: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(3321): GCM IntentService class: com.google.glass.home.GCMIntentService

06-25 21:54:39.669: V/GCMBaseIntentService(3321): Acquiring wakelock

06-25 21:54:39.677: V/GCMBaseIntentService(3321): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-229668747847-712

06-25 21:54:39.685: I/GCMIntentService(3321): Received message: Bundle[{p=timeline_sync, from=229668747847, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

06-25 21:54:39.763: V/GCMBaseIntentService(3321): Releasing wakelock

06-25 21:54:39.778: I/SyncHelper(3321): Requesting sync 

[authority=com.google.glass.sync.timeline, syncSource=GCM,
extras=Bundle[{ignore_backoff=true}]].

06-25 21:54:39.872: I/TimelineSyncAdapter(3377): Entering onPerformSync [authority= com.google.glass.sync.timeline, extras=Bundle[{sync_priority=0, ignore_backoff=true}]].

06-25 21:54:39.911: I/DownloadSyncHelper(3377): Fetching unsynced items from server.

06-25 21:54:39.950: I/DownloadSyncHelper(3377): Requesting sync 
[window=TimelineSyncWindow{startTime=1403747642036001, continuationToken=null}].

06-25 21:54:39.989: I/TimelineItemDatabaseHelper(3377): Getting unsynced items with sync protocols: 0, 1

06-25 21:54:40.067: W/GLSUser(3573): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()

06-25 21:54:40.130: D/ConnectivityService(3122): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=100

06-25 21:54:40.130: D/ConnectivityService(3122): sendStickyBroadcast: action=android.net.conn.INET_CONDITION_ACTION

06-25 21:54:40.317: I/EyeGestureService(3122): Retrieving persistent state of detection for gesture DON.

06-25 21:54:40.325: I/DownloadSyncHelper(3377): Received items from server [count=1].

06-25 21:54:40.380: I/TimelineProvider(3377): Overwrote timeline item 8a3d2908-437e-47b7-
b985-5c07a99f3e32 because existing modified time (1403742250447) < new modified time (1403747648937)

06-25 21:54:40.505: I/SyncStats(3377): Download api:582969681302 [numFiles=1, totalBytes=2kB, totalDuration=375ms].

06-25 21:54:40.528: W/ActivityManager(3122): Sleep timeout!  Sleeping now.

06-25 21:54:40.911: I/MainTimelineView(3321): New timeline database content loaded; updating views.

06-25 21:54:40.942: I/MainTimelineView(3321): New timeline database content loaded; updating views.

06-25 21:54:46.028: W/ActivityManager(3122): Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{20ede224 u0 com.kjacksonmusic.glassrta/.RTAactivity t1}
```

Comment: If possible decrease the buffer size till 1024 to 2048. Unable to load large data in buffer.

Comment: Thanks Log posted let me know if you need more then that?

Comment: Anil I tried using your suggestions with sample rate and it comes back in logcat: 06-25 22:32:29.052: E/AndroidRuntime(21794): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2048Hz is not a supported sample rate.

Comment: I will add that when the service is started the Activity does display properly, the TextViews just don't update what so ever and then it becomes unresponsive and the activity seems to be destroyed.